# Alternatives to using NSDrawer

Tags: user-interface, cocoa, user-experience, appkit

I'm currently prototyping a potential app where the user would be managing a primary list. What I would like is for the ability of an alternate list to slide out so both lists would appear side by side. This would allow the user to transfer items between the two via drag and drop. Since the main workflow would be on the primary list most of the time, it seems like it would be cleaner if most of the time, the alternate list is hidden.

To me, it seems like using `NSDrawer` would be a good fit. However it's deprecated. And I'm assuming it's impossible to build an app which has an 'L' shape or inverted 'T' shape.

So I was thinking of potential alternatives which I could try out.

Some ones I though of were

- Expanding the window width to accommodate a split view. And shrink when done
- Create a new `NSWindow` but find a way to always pin it to the side. So if either window were moved, the other would move with it.
- Just use another `NSWindow` and don't care about the pinning. In theory I could always open it next to the other window and let the user worry about managing any movement.

Has anyone had any success in replicating an `NSDrawer` type of alternative?

Comment: See [Drawers](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/drawers/) in the Human Interface Guidelines[Drawers](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/drawers/) in the Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: I'd recommend against your second option (pinning windows together). It's ugly-looking and unintuitive. In fact, that's essentially what a drawer does, just with some bells and whistles, which is why they are deprecated. And yes, you could make a window that was an inverted T, as long as you can define the shape programmatically, but why??? Option 1 (split view) strikes me as the best bet, or if you don't want to animate the window size just create a second 'transfer' window and invoke it at need.

Comment: @TedWrigley thanks for the suggestions. One other detail I left out is the main window is fixed in width. It originates as an `NSPopover` on the status bar. So widening would have some issues.  What about not pinning, but opening the alternate window so it is next to the main window? But the use can freely move it afterwards. The reason I'm asking that is I'm on dual monitors. I have some apps I use where window I open from the app (like tool panels in Adobe products) end up on the other monitor or in some weird location and I find it annoying I have to spend time searching for the window.

Comment: Well, if you're doing this as a menu bar popover, I'd suggest using the popover just to show the list, but with an edit button: when the edit button gets clicked it closes the popup and opens a standard panel with a split view that shows both the main and alternate lists. Menu bar items (and popups) are supposed to be lightweight and temporary; any real work should be done in an app window.